# Azure DevOps pipelines resource trigger not working

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline (Pipeline1) that should be triggered when another (Pipeline2) completes. To that end I have implemented a pipelines resource as described in the documentation -

- [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#resources)

However, it's simply not working. In reality **Pipeline2** will be triggered when a new PR is created or manually. I've tested creating a new PR, updating a PR several times, and several manual runs, but no matter what I do **Pipeline1** will not trigger.

I've tried two of the examples as defined in the YAML schema reference, and reading further into the [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) document, I've tried to prefix the all branches wildcard with `refs/heads/`.

What must I do to get this working?

### What I've tried

Without any `branchs` explicitly defined -

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline2
      source: Pipeline2
      trigger: true
```

With all `branches` explicitly defined -

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline2
      source: Pipeline2
      trigger:
        branches:
          - "*"
```

Prefixed the all `branches` wildcard with `refs/heads/` -

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline2
      source: Pipeline2
      trigger:
        branches:
          - refs/heads/*
```

---

## Update

It seems that sadly the `pipelines` resource does not work on PR's. Why That's the case, I couldn't tell you.

After some further investigation I stumbled across the [**Incoming Webhook** Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines) in a sprint update. This update is from six months ago and at the time of writing nothing has been added to the [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#resources).

However, it turns out that this feature just [doesn't work](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1135943/cannot-use-generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml.html) full stop, and even if it did it looks like it will only trigger the default branch of a pipeline, which is no good for us (and probably no good for most use cases).

I did eventually find some [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md) from a year ago, but unfortunately this only seems to confirm that the [**Incoming Webhook** Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines) is of no use to us in this case.

Comment: Hi @DavidGard, how about set the  'Build completion' trigger via the classic editor? Does it work?

Comment: No idea, not something I'm going to try I'm afraid. We've run in to issues when mixing classic and YAML in the past, so I don't want to risk it on this occasion.

Comment: Okay, @DavidGard. If you want to configure the pipeline definition just in the YAML file, you should make sure have disabled or removed the settings you set via the classic editor.

Comment: @DavidGard Did by any chance have this tested across two repositories. I do have the exact same problem and cannot seem to get it to work. All default branches set correctly in both repos as far as I can tell. 
Also I do get trigger configuration error on the pipeline to be triggered but no further info whatsoever.

Comment: Are you __concluding__ that pipeline triggers don't work on pr's or did you find some official evidence of that?

Answer (score 26):

[This answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pipeline-trigger-not-working-as-expressed-in-docum/864701) solved it for me.

I had a `main` and `dev` branch, and the target pipeline yaml file was not yet pushed up to `main`. The "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" in the target pipeline must contain the source file in order for the pipeline to be triggered automatically. (The version of the pipeline that will actually be triggered will be the branch that triggered the original pipeline, as long as they are in the same project.) I changed the value to `dev` and that solved it.

You can change this setting by going to Edit/Triggers/Yaml/Get sources:

[image: Change setting]

Comment: Here is the MS official documentation on what Rachel P is talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-default-branch?view=azure-devops

Comment: For me, it didn't work with the default value it had... at first. I switched it to a topic branch, then my pipelines started working correctly again. Then I switched back to the original value... and it kept on working. ¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?

Comment: Instead of switching the default branch from master/main. I pushed the 2nd pipeline to master. Then the triggers in my other environment branches started to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me works this

```yaml
resources:        
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build_pipeline  
    source: kmadof.devops-manual (14)
    branch: master
    trigger:
     branches:
     - '*'

steps:
- bash: env | sort
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Hello world'
```

[image]

So in your case I would try this:

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline2
      source: Pipeline2
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          - '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`Pipeline2`** is triggered by PR, so the source branch (**`Build.SourceBranch`**) that triggers the pipeline run is the PR merge branch (**`refs/pull/{PR_ID}/merge`**).

I also have tested with the 3 ways you posted above, and only the first way can work as expected.

According to my further investigation, it seems that the branch filters on the pipeline resource trigger are only available to the repository branches that you can see on the '**Repos/Branches**' page. These branches have the same prefix '**`refs/heads/`**'. The PR merge branch (**`refs/pull/{PR_ID}/merge`**) seems is not included.

In your case, the first way should can work. You need to check with the following things:

1. Make sure you have specified the correct pipeline name of **Pipeline2** to the '**`source`**' key.
2. Check whether **Pipeline1** and **Pipeline2** are in the same project. If not, make sure you have used the '**`project`**' key to specify the correct project where **Pipeline2** is in, and make sure the projects are in the same organization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the correct `source` and the pipelines are in the same project. If this won't work with PR's then unfortunately it's an entirely pointless endeavour. Hopefully this is something that MS will fix quickly.

Comment: Hi @DavidGard, Ideally, both the first way and the second way should work for PR, but currently only the first way works according to my test. In your case, none of them can work. You also can try to check if you have set 'Build completion' trigger on the classic editor for your 'Pipeline1' (`Edit` > `┆` > `triggers`). the triggers set on the classic editor will override the triggers set in the YAML file. If you do not set trigger on the classic editor, you can try use the classic editor to see if the 'Build completion' trigger can work.