Allow user to specify version for Azure YAML deploy pipeline
I'm trying to create a deploy pipeline in YAML that can be manually run by users.  I want them to be able to select the version of the artifact generated using a dropdown list.  I've been able to do it with a text box input using a string parameter, but a better/safer user experience would be to present them with the valid values in a dropdown.
My build pipeline sets the BuildNumber using this convention:
$versionFull=1.2.3-branchname
echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$versionFull"

I have a task to publish the artifact to the pipeline in this build pipeline.
I don't think this is relevant, but we host in AWS, so I also upload the artifact to S3 so I can easily use CodeDeploy (or other scripts) to deploy the artifacts.
My original attempt was a single YAML pipeline with both build and deploy functionality.  I was hoping the UI would allow my users to pick just the deploy stage, then somehow specify the desired artifact version.  Then it seemed wise to split it into two separate YAML pipelines:  one for build, one for deploy.  The deploy one could be configured to automatically run for certain triggers, too.

Yes. It should be wise to split the Pipeline into two separate Yaml Pipelines for build and deploy based on your situation.
Based on your description, you need to let uses can select the artifacts version in Deploy Pipeline.
I suggest that you can use the Pipeline resources in Deploy Pipeline.
Here is an example:
Build Pipeline
.....
steps:
....
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'output'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Deploy Pipeline:
resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: source-pipeline
     source: Pipelinename
     project: Projectname
     trigger: true


steps:
- download: source-pipeline 

When you run the Pipeline, you can select the related Pipeline Artifacts version.


I've been playing around with resources and just haven't gotten this far.  Thanks!  I'll report back if this accomplishes my goal.

@MatthewAllen Feel free to let me know the result. If you have any further questions, you can share with me.

this did the trick.  When I manually ran the app-deploy.yml pipeline, I was able to pick a specific run of the app-build.yml pipeline using the Resources popup.  I was having problems getting it to run automatically, though.  I referred to this thread to fix that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739940/azure-devops-pipelines-resource-trigger-not-working
